# How to calculate stock pullback

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to calculate the pullback (percentage change) off of its high. Not necessarily change from high to today, but percentage change from high to the lowest point after that high.

Where I am drawing a blank, is I don't know where to begin with finding the lowest point in the stock **after** the high for the stock. I can find the high for each stock, but how do I trim that column so that it only has the stock prices **after** that high?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import pandas.io.data as web

stocks = ['AAPL', 'NFLX', 'MSFT', 'MCD', 'DIS']
start = dt.datetime(2015, 1, 1)
end = dt.datetime.today()

df = web.DataReader(stocks, 'yahoo', start, end)
df = df['Close']
dfMax = df.max()
```

From here, I have 5 columns, one column for each stock, and the subsequent prices on each day. I am stumped...

Comment: Are you looking for something like :`for col in df:
    sl = df.loc[df[col].idxmax():, col]
    print('Stock: ', col, 'max diff: ', sl.max() - sl.min())`

Comment: I can't tell if the min is coming from the entire df, or if it is the min after the max?

Comment: My code takes a slice with the max as the starting range, so the `min` is now for all values after the max so conceptually it should be what you want I think

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to use the Adj Close price so that you can accurately measure daily returns (i.e. so your results aren't impacted by splits and dividends).

To calculate the forward min (i.e. the lowest point AFTER the most recent max high), perform a `cummin` on the prices sorted in reverse order, and then reverse again:  `df[::-1].cummin()[::-1]`.

The pullback from the cumulative max price is one minus the ratio of this forward min price to the cumulative max price: `1 - df[::-1].cummin()[::-1] / df.cummax()`

```
df = web.DataReader(stocks, 'yahoo', start, end)['Adj Close']

df_pullback = 1 - df[::-1].cummin()[::-1] / df.cummax()
df_pullback.plot()
```

[image]

Comment: I am a little confused, is the chart showing the pullback from the high at that point in time?

Comment: I must admit, I found the question confusing because it relies on future prices that occur after the high.  As a result, previously calculated values in the chart will change if the most recent price were to achieve a new low from the previous high. Usually one shows the current drawdown from the most recent high (or possibly the cum max drawdown from that high).  Your question, however, asked how to find "the lowest point in the stock after the high for the stock". The chart thus show, for each date, the pullback from the highest high preceding that date to the lowest low following that date.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Apologies for the confusion, I am simply trying to calculate the pullback for each stock. As in, what is the high for the entire period, then find the low for the period from high to today.

Comment: You should limit yourself to one question per post.  If this response answered the question, please tick the green tick mark to indicate that it is the accepted answer.  If you have a new related question, please post it and I'll respond separately.